# First date where userID appears in dataframe in R

Tags: r

I want to group data by rows in a dataframe. Each user has a unique userID, and each user might appear several times in the dataframe. There is a column for each time they appear. So, for example, user01 might have logged in on 10-01-2014 and 10-02-2014, so user01 will appear in two rows.

I want the first instance each user appeared. How can I do this in R or Excel? I feel like this would be easy to do in SQL, so I must be missing something obvious...

Comment: you should show some data ; but basically, `library(dplyr) ; group_by(df,userid) %>% arrange(date) %>% filter(row_number() == 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the first appearance, one can use the "min" command on a data object:

```
#sort id by order of first arrival
first<-tapply(df$arrival_date, df$userID, min)
first<-sort(as.Date(first, origin = "1970-01-01"))
```

The tapply command coverts the as.Date column to numeric thus the need to reconvert back to a date class.

Answer (score 1):

In R you could do

```
df <- read.table(col.names=c("date", "user"), text='"10-01-2014" "user1"
"10-02-2014" "user1"
"10-01-2015" "user2"
"10-02-2015" "user2"')
df$date <- as.Date(df$date, "%d-%m-%Y")
aggregate(date~user, df, head, 1)
#    user       date
# 1 user1 2014-01-10
# 2 user2 2015-01-10
```

If you need to order the data, do `df <- df[order(df$user, df$date), ]` beforehand.